# PHP regex bug not respecting linebreak

Tags: php, regex

Okay, so I've got something of a weird edge case bug that I can't seem to squash.

I've got a textarea form input where users can type status updates. I've built a method to parse through this and autolink http-links (except for a few domains where I use the Essence library to do some oEmbed magic).

But in a very specific edge case the autolink complete buggers out.

Specifically, when there's url to a subdirectory, without an ending slash, where immediately after the url the user does a carriage return to a new line and keeps typing. 
When this happens the first word on the new line is included in the url being matched.

The function looks like this:

```
function autolink( $text, $attributes=array() ) {
    $regex = "/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z0-9]{2,99}(\/\S*)?/i";

    $urls = array();

    if( preg_match_all( $regex, $text, $urls, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER ) ) {

        foreach($urls[0] as $url) {

            $parsed_url = parse_url($url);

            if( in_array( $parsed_url['host'], array( 'youtube.com', 'vimeo.com', 'soundcloud.com', 'www.youtube.com', 'www.vimeo.com', 'www.soundcloud.com' ) ) ) {

                $essence = Essence\Essence::instance();
                $media = $essence->embed( $url );
                $text = str_replace($url, '<div class="embed-container">'.$media->html.'</div>', $text);

            } else {

                $attrs = '';
                foreach( $attributes as $attribute => $value ) {
                  $attrs .= " {$attribute}=\"{$value}\"";
                }

                $text = str_replace($url,'<a href="'.$url.'"'.$attrs.'>'.$url.'</a>', $text);

            }


        }
    }
    $text = '<pre>'.print_r($urls, true).'</pre>'.$text;

    $text = trim( $text );
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your regex `"~(http|https)://[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z0-9]{2,99}(/\\S*)?~"` that would allow any whitespace. Are you saying it matched a linebreak? Show and highlight exactly what you are talking about.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it any clearer. I tried to add an example, but the markdown rendering here won't allow it.

Comment: I'm just trying to help. You have to show a specific output text sample that demonstrates your problem. You can put the output into a <code> markup, or just use back ticks to highlight the exact text.

Comment: I totally understand that you're trying to help, and I do really appreciate it. I'm just very much unsure of what you're asking of me? Is it the resulting output you want to see?

Comment: Yeah, just put what the regex matched into a code block so we can take a look at it.

Comment: This question does not provide a [mcve] and must be closed as Needs Details or Needs Debugging Details.